# combine multiple mp4 videos and images

Tags: python-3.x, video, command-line, ffmpeg, mp4

so I have a folder of images, 1/20 named `*.png` and a folder of mp4's named `*.mp4`.

I want to create a video in this order:

- `1.png` for 3 sec
- `1.mp4`
- `2.png` for 3 sec
- `3.mp4`
- etc

Is there a way I can display each png for 3 seconds and then show the respective mp4 using `ffmpeg`? I know I can convert each picture to a 3 second video invididually using this command and the framerate differences will be a problem (1/3 vs 60), but I'm not very experienced with command line video editing:

```
ffmpeg -r 1/3 -i 1.png -vcodec mpeg4 1_intro.mp4
```

ffprobe output:

```
ffprobe version 4.0 Copyright (c) 2007-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.0 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox --disable-lzma
  libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
  libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
  libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
  libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
  libpostproc    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
  Duration: 00:00:32.69, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 7039 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt709/unknown/unknown), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 7004 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 90k tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 43 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

output of `out.mp4`

```
ffprobe version 4.0 Copyright (c) 2007-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.0 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox --disable-lzma
  libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
  libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
  libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
  libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
  libpostproc    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'out.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.12.100
  Duration: 00:10:19.13, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5689 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 2560x1440 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 5565 kb/s, 53.91 fps, 60 tbr, 90k tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 114 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

Comment: Are the videos the same framerate? Audio in any of them?

Comment: all have audio, i think they have the same framerate. How can I check?

Comment: look for `gst-launch`

Comment: all videos are 60 fps

Comment: @Gyan any ideas? Would it be possible to do at all?

Comment: Share the output of `ffprobe 1.mp4`

Comment: @Gyan edited post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each image, run

```
ffmpeg -i image -f lavfi -i anullsrc -r 60 -pix_fmt yuv420p -ac 2 -ar 44100 -video_track_timescale 90k -t 3 image.mp4
```

Then create a text file,

```
file img1.mp4
file 1.mp4
file img2.mp4
file 2.mp4
...etc
```

and run

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i list.txt -c copy out.mp4
```

This whole process assumes that the MP4s have the same properties, like resolution..etc.

Comment: that's awesome! Having an issue with the out.mp4 video overlay, do you want me to open another question or just discuss.

Comment: New Q. I'll see it in the morning.