# ffmpeg combining mp4 videos incorrectly

Tags: video, command-line, ffmpeg, mp4

i have a list of 20 mp4 files that I need to combine into one video. They are all 60 FPS, but range in size. In between each mp4 file I need to show its 'intro', a 1.5 second clip about the file.

Reference:

- `pics/i.png` - intro for the nth mp4 file
- `clips/i_intro.mp4` - mp4 intro generated from i.png
- `clips/i.mp4` - original mp4
- `clips/i_resize.mp4` - 720p mp4

Here is what I've done:

Convert image to mp4 using this command (taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50765926/combine-multiple-mp4-videos-and-images)):

`ffmpeg -y -i pics/{i}.png -f lavfi -i anullsrc -r 60 -pix_fmt yuv420p -ac 2 -ar 44100 -video_track_timescale 90k -t 1.5 clips/{i}_intro.mp4`

Convert `i.mp4` to 720p using this command (taken from [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/352920/fastest-way-to-convert-videos-batch-or-single)):

`ffmpeg -i clips/{i}.mp4 -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset medium -c:a aac -b:a 128k -vf scale=-2:720,format=yuv420p {i}_resize.mp4`

Created a file like this:

```
file 1_intro.mp4
file 1_resize.mp4
file 2_intro.mp4
file 2_resize.mp4
...
```

Combine all clips:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i {video_list} -c copy out.mp4
```

This generates a file, but it is definitely messed up. When I combined the files I got a ton of warning messages like this:

```
[mp4 @ 0x7f88fe01de00] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0;
previous: 48966232, current: 8826932; changing to 48966233. This may
result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
```

FFprobe for `out.mp4`

```
ffprobe version 4.0 Copyright (c) 2007-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.0 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox --disable-lzma
  libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
  libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
  libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
  libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
  libpostproc    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'out.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.12.100
  Duration: 00:09:35.56, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4119 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 4221 kb/s, 59.98 fps, 351.56 tbr, 90k tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 122 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

FFprobe for `1.mp4`

```
ffprobe version 4.0 Copyright (c) 2007-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.0 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox --disable-lzma
  libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
  libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
  libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
  libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
  libpostproc    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
  Duration: 00:00:40.94, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 7613 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt709/unknown/unknown), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 7451 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 90k tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 160 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

FFprobe for `1_resized.mp4`

```
ffprobe version 4.0 Copyright (c) 2007-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.0 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox --disable-lzma
  libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
  libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
  libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
  libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
  libpostproc    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '1_resize.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.12.100
  Duration: 00:00:32.37, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3266 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 3127 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 129 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

FFprobe for `1_intro.mp4`

```
ffprobe version 4.0 Copyright (c) 2007-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.0 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox --disable-lzma
  libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
  libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
  libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
  libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
  libpostproc    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '1_intro.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.12.100
  Duration: 00:00:01.52, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 113 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 4667 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 90k tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 2 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

I noticed that the length of the files are different, and the `tbn` in different, but idk what that means. Thanks for helping!

Comment: @Gyan i need you bro

Comment: Add `-video_track_timescale 90k` to your resizing command. You can skip audio re-encoding using `-c:a copy`

Comment: ill try it thanks!

Comment: can I set it lower? it takes awfully long to encode and its 1.5x larger

Comment: `video_track_timescale` has no bearing on video file size or encoding speed.